# nonlinear regression prediction in R

Tags: r, prediction, non-linear-regression, drc

I am confused by this warning message as I try to fit my data with a nonlinear regression model by using the drc package and drm function.

I have

```
 N_obs <- c(1, 80, 80, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 84, 95, 102, 102, 102, 103, 104, 105, 105, 109, 111, 117, 120, 123, 123, 124, 126, 127, 128, 128, 129, 130)

 times <- c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32)
```

The model is

```
  model.drm <- drm(N_obs ~ times, data = data.frame(N_obs = N_obs, times = times), fct = MM.2())
```

and the warnings come from predictions

```
  preds <- predict(model.drm, times = times, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95)

There were 30 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In (tquan * sqrt(varVal + sumObjRV)) * c(-1, 1) :
Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
Use c() or as.vector() instead.
2: In (tquan * sqrt(varVal + sumObjRV)) * c(-1, 1) :
Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
Use c() or as.vector() instead.

3: In (tquan * sqrt(varVal + sumObjRV)) * c(-1, 1) :
Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

I have been trying to change data inputs by using as.vector(times), c(times),etc., but still cannot get rid of the warnings. Could someone help me identify the problem? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that reproduce the warnings? Do the warnings originate from `drm` or from `predict`? `drm` (as most non-linear fitting routines) can be very sensitive to starting values etc. Also a warning doesn't necessarily mean that the model fit failed. Details such as sample data would help!

Comment: Thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I re-ran your analysis with the sample data provided, and I can reproduce your warnings. Here's a summary:

1. Fit a [Michaelis-Menten model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) of the form `f(x; d, e) = d * (1 + e/x)^-1`.

   ```
   # Fit a 2 parameter Michaelis-Menten model
   library(drc);
   fit <- drm(
       formula = N_obs ~ times,
       data = data.frame(N_obs = N_obs, times = times),
       fct = MM.2())
   ```
2. Based on the model fit, `predict` the response for the original `times`. Note you can omit the `newdata` argument here, because in that case `predict` will simply use the fitted values (which are based on `times`).

   ```
   # Predictions
   pred <- as.data.frame(predict(
       fit,
       newdata = data.frame(N_obs = N_obs, times = times),
       interval = "confidence", level = 0.95));
   pred$times <- times;
   ```
3. Visualise data and predictions.

   ```
   library(tidyverse);
   data.frame(times = times, N_obs = N_obs) %>%
       ggplot(aes(times, N_obs)) +
           geom_point() +
           geom_line(data = pred, aes(x = times, y = Prediction)) +
           geom_ribbon(
               data = pred,
               aes(x = times, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),
               alpha = 0.4);
   ```

[image]

The model fit seems reasonable, and I would say that the `warnings` can be safely ignored (see details).

### Details

I had a look at the `drc` source-code, and the warning originates from line `201` of `predict.drc.R`:

```
retMat[rowIndex, 3:4] <- retMat[rowIndex, 1] + (tquan * sqrt(varVal + sumObjRV)) * c(-1, 1)
```

In that line, an array of dimension 1 is added to a numeric vector.

Here is a simple example to reproduce the warning:

```
arr <- array(5, dim = 1);
arr + c(1, 2);
#[1] 6 7
#Warning message:
#In arr + c(1, 2) :
#  Recycling array of length 1 in array-vector arithmetic is deprecated.
#  Use c() or as.vector() instead.
```

Note that the result is still correct; it's just that R doesn't like the addition of a one-dimensional array and a vector, and prefers instead adding proper scalars and vectors, or vectors and vectors.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps a lot! :)